# Making users display name searchable in display template

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, display-template, managed-property

I have a search display template showing some documents based on a content type and one of the fields `DocOwner`, which is a people field.

Using javascript it is simple enough to get the user's display name from the account id `B5241@tenant.sharepoint.com` and show that.

However the end users are requesting that they should be able to search for the documents owned by a user using the display name like `John Scalzi`.

I have not been able to find any mapping of managed properties that enables that, so I wonder if it is posible?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you create your own managed property for your custom field? Or you can also add filters/refiners to left side of search results page which will help your team to filter the documents based on user names.

Comment: I have tried mapping both the ows_DocOwner and the ows_q_user_DocOwner to managed properties but both seems to contain the account id , not the display name . I am currently using a custom refiner template that does show the display name via js

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible using KQL (Keyword Query Language). For this simple need, it is enough to write the following code in the search box:

```
author:"John Scalzi"
```

this return all the document that are creating by John Scalzi. If you need to make it more flexible you can use a content search webpart and pass the {searchquery} to it from search box in this way:

```
author:{searchquery}
```

and link the search box to content search web part and then user only need the user name in the search box (Any user name!)

**Update**:

Yes, It is right but you can make other fields searchable too.

If you have centeral admin access you can do it from there otherwise follow below steps:

1. Go to site level
2. Go to search schema
3. Go to Managed Property.
4. Search the column you want to search then enable the checkbox related to Searchable and Queryable related to that column.

For example you have a field named `DocOwner` then you should see a field like `DocOwnerOWSUser` in Managed Property which is mapped to `OWS_User_DocOwner` (if it doesnt make the mapping).

You should enable the `Queryable` and `Searchable` checkbox for this field. (PS: I am ready for Remote Helping if it is necessary just Email me to `abdollahkahne@gmail.com`)

Comment: Unfortunately this only applies for the Author field. In this case the DocOwner field only contains the user account like i:0#.f|membership|b5241j@tenant.com :-(   but thanks for the answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

Please link the `RefinableString00:OWS_DocOwner`in the Managed Properties.
Then use this query at content search :

```
RefinableString00:{searchquery}
```

Add a search webpart and link it to content Query and you should see the following results:
[image]
[image]
[image]